# robot_localization GPS causing large drift/covariance spike

Tags: ros, localization, kalman-filter, ekf, ros-humble

I am trying to implement the dual ekf navsat [example](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/humble-devel/params/dual_ekf_navsat_example.yaml) on my real-world robot.  The local EKF with wheel odometry and IMU works quite well and has no issues.  As far as I can tell, my global EKF configuration is nearly identical to the local with the only addition being the /odometry/gps.

When I start both nodes, the map->odom transform blows up in X/Y and spins randomly when sitting stationary.  I have tried adjusting process noise covariance and initial covariance estimate parameters, but these appear to not change the issue.

My GPS appears to be working well.  I have RTK Fix and it reports an accuracy of ~2cm, which my testing appears to validate.

**Bag file:**

I recorded a bag file of the robot sitting still, then drawing a rectangle.  The odometry/local appears to draw the shape relatively well.  Observing the path of the GPS points also shows relatively low noise, and draws the path well.  I can't upload on this site, here is a [sharepoint/onedrive link](https://purdue0-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/brow1633_purdue_edu/ESeVDWPf47VGnnv4pgDwNC0ByIKr5bvzTdqsUpP7oE4MeA?e=tSUei9).

Here is a graph showing the /odometry/global (left) vs /odometry/gps and /odometry/local (right):

[image: image description]

**Details:**

- Platform: Nvidia Jetson Xavier
- ROS Version: ROS2 Humble
- Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04 (docker image: arm64v8/ros:humble-perception-jammy)
- Robot_Localization version: 3.5.1-2 (20230525)
- GPS Driver: [septentrio-gnss](https://github.com/septentrio-gnss/septentrio_gnss_driver)

**robot_localization config:**

(Process/Initial cov matricies are identical to [example](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/humble-devel/params/dual_ekf_navsat_example.yaml))

```
ekf_filter_node_odom:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    sensor_timeout: 0.1
    two_d_mode: true
    transform_time_offset: 0.0
    transform_timeout: 0.0
    print_diagnostics: true
    debug: false

    map_frame: map
    odom_frame: odom
    base_link_frame: base_link
    world_frame: odom

    odom0: diff_cont/odom
    odom0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  false, false, true,
                  false, false, false]
    odom0_queue_size: 10
    odom0_nodelay: true
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_relative: false

    imu0: zed2i/zed_node/imu/data
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  false,
                  false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  true,  true,  true]
    imu0_nodelay: false
    imu0_differential: false
    imu0_relative: false
    imu0_queue_size: 10
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    use_control: false

ekf_filter_node_map:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    sensor_timeout: 0.1
    two_d_mode: true
    transform_time_offset: 0.0
    transform_timeout: 0.0
    print_diagnostics: true
    debug: false

    map_frame: map
    odom_frame: odom
    base_link_frame: base_link
    world_frame: map

    odom0: diff_cont/odom
    odom0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  false, false, true,
                  false, false, false]
    odom0_queue_size: 10
    odom0_nodelay: true
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_relative: false

    imu0: zed2i/zed_node/imu/data
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  false, false, false,
                  false,  false,  false,
                  false,  false,  false]
    imu0_nodelay: false
    imu0_differential: false
    imu0_relative: false
    imu0_queue_size: 10
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    odom1: odometry/gps
    odom1_config: [true,  true,  false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false]
    odom1_queue_size: 10
    odom1_nodelay: true
    odom1_differential: false
    odom1_relative: false


    use_control: false

navsat_transform:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    delay: 3.0
    magnetic_declination_radians: 0.0
    yaw_offset: 0.0
    zero_altitude: false
    broadcast_utm_transform: true
    publish_filtered_gps: true
    use_odometry_yaw: false
    wait_for_datum: false
```

**Example Sensor Messages:**

diff_cont/odom:

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1688561428
    nanosec: 748273568
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
  covariance:
  - 0.001
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.001
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.001
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.001
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.001
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 1.0e-06
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance:
  - 0.001
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.001
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.001
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.001
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.001
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 1.0e-06
```

/zed2i/zed_node/imu/data:

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1688561477
    nanosec: 94539456
  frame_id: zed2i_imu_link
orientation:
  x: 0.04747530817985535
  y: 0.0217120498418808
  z: 0.33702659606933594
  w: 0.9400466680526733
orientation_covariance:
- 5.814558282399458e-10
- -3.2944193591010685e-10
- 3.0220212313595557e-11
- -3.294419012791137e-10
- 8.316236808529003e-10
- 2.0890566503682616e-10
- 3.022021664246969e-11
- 2.0890566503682616e-10
- 6.456938962255484e-10
angular_velocity:
  x: -0.01820158927202928
  y: 0.02127879501425481
  z: 0.000792325946237065
angular_velocity_covariance:
- 6.35957531046334e-10
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 6.81844497277238e-10
- 0.0
- 0.0
- -0.0
- 5.81403604702388e-10
linear_acceleration:
  x: 0.024594472721219063
  y: 1.1347548961639404
  z: 9.869213104248047
linear_acceleration_covariance:
- 0.005106136202812195
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.00590071314945817
- 0.0
- 0.0
- -0.0
- 0.006188959814608097
```

gps/fix:

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1688561423
    nanosec: 145409472
  frame_id: gps_frame
status:
  status: 2
  service: 9
latitude: 48.477501743301964
longitude: -82.00108049977172
altitude: 232.53988211053635
position_covariance:
- 0.00017811922589316964
- -6.650557043030858e-05
- -1.604144199518487e-05
- -6.650557043030858e-05
- 0.0003876265836879611
- -6.546182703459635e-06
- -1.604144199518487e-05
- -6.546182703459635e-06
- 0.0009483876056037843
position_covariance_type: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to look at; with wheel encoders/IMU your coordinate system will be relative (local) to the robot.  With GPS the coordinate system will be a global system aligned to the Earth.  So to fuse these two you must align the wheel encoder/IMU coordinate system to the global system.  You can validate this by manually placing the starting position of the robot so it is aligned to the global system so that fusing the two should work without any other software alignment.